# torch.topk vs torch.tensor.max()

Tags: python, pytorch

Has anyone tried comparing the values output by the above 2 functions ? I have a problem where i want to obtain the top 2 values in the dim 0 of a tensor. When i tried to compare the outputs of the above 2 functions, i am seeing the following trend:

1. The max values are equal in all cases
2. The co-ordinates are not equal

My code, for reference:

```
    for step,batch_data in enumerate(val_loader):
       inputs = batch_data[0].to("cuda")
       target = batch_data[1].squeeze().numpy()


       with torch.no_grad():
           outputs = model(inputs)

       x,prediction = outputs.squeeze().max(0)
       y,top_indices = torch.topk(outputs.squeeze(),k=2,dim=0)
```

I used torch.equal to compare x,y[0,:,:] and predictions and top_indices[0,:,:] -- Basically corresponding to the top value in that dimension

Like mentioned above, x and y[0,:,:] are matching while predictions and top_indices[0,:,:] are not.

TO REPRODUCE THE ERROR -- Sometimes the values wont match:

```
    for i in range(100):
      demo_tensor = torch.randn(3,256,256).to("cuda")
      max_1,coord_1 = demo_tensor.max(dim=0)
      max_2,coord_2 = torch.topk(demo_tensor,k=2,dim=0)
      if torch.equal(max_1,max_2[0,:,:])and
          torch.equal(coord_1,coord_2[0,:,:]):
         print("Values match")
      else:
         print("No match")

      print("\n")
```

Comment: Please provide some code (with random tensors initialized) to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @Ivan have added the necessary code to my post. Please give it a try. At some iterations, the values won't match.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error, it always returns that both are True.

Comment: @Ivan Thank you for trying. That's interesting. Let me try it in another machine and let you know, just to be sure it's not my hardware -- a precision error or the like.

Comment: In that case, try using [`isclose`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.isclose.html) instead of `equal`, this may help compare the two in case of precision errors.

Comment: @Ivan It looks like its just a hardware based issue of sorts. I am not able to see a "no match" now. I think, like we agreed, it may be just be something related to precision. Thanks for your help!